# jquery selector cannot find tbody Datatable filled with JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

Maybe some of you already have encountered my problem : i use a `<table>` which is filled with JSON. On the html part, i create only `<table>` and `<tbody>`. 
It works fine, but when i want to select tbody whith Jquery :
`$('#mytable tbody')`, the tbody is not find !
CSS and firebug are able to see the tbody, but not Jquery !

Do you know a way to select the tbody by using jquery ?

Comment: are you using datatables plugin?

Comment: Yes : select plugin, and fixedheader plugin

Comment: can you add a Jsfiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have not time now to add an example in JsFiddle now, i will try to do it tonight.

Comment: Could you please paste the HTML code complete?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things.

1. Find the Child select with Jquery.
2. Move into your " " to find it. For instants:

I'll recommend you use the choice 2, but could appear some problems to find the `<tbody>` tag, because this depends of the parent of this tag. I mean, if you have something like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

You have to find it, like css, with the ID and the corresponding inheritance for find it. So, to find the element `<tbody>`, you have to:

```
$('table#mytable > tbody ')
```

If you paste this table#mytable > tbody on CSS style document, maybe you could see that your selector will appear because you are inheriting since the id to the `<tbody>` tag, and not taking only tbody without a >

Comment: Thank you, but $('table#mytable > tbody ')  doesn't work.     I have to make a demo with Jsfiddle, it will be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using :

```
var oTable = $('#my_table').DataTable();
var cells = oTable.column( 1 ).nodes();  // first column is number 0
$( cells ).addClass('highlight');  // for each <td> ...
```

You can also select only the TDs which contain "none" :

```
var cells = oTable.cells( ":contains('none')" ).nodes();
```

I am not sure these functions are available with Jquery, i think they come from the DataTable library.

Comment: They are part of dataTables library